# Template is null for featured products

Tags: php, magento2

I am trying to create a product list for featured products in Magento.
I wrote the following code in the file `app/code/MyModule/MySite/Block/Products/Featured.php`:

```
<?php

namespace MyModule\MySite\Block\Products;

class Featured extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct
{
    /**
     * Catalog product visibility
     *
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility
     */
    protected $_catalogProductVisibility;

    /**
     * Product collection factory
     *
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory
     */
    protected $_productCollectionFactory;


    /**
     * @var CategoryRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $categoryRepository;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Helper\PostHelper $postDataHelper,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver $layerResolver,
        \Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface $categoryRepository,
        \Magento\Framework\Url\Helper\Data $urlHelper,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility $catalogProductVisibility,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
        array $data = []

    ) {
        $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
        $this->_catalogProductVisibility = $catalogProductVisibility;
        parent::__construct($context, $postDataHelper, $layerResolver,$categoryRepository,$urlHelper,$data);
    }

    protected function _getProductCollection(){
        $collection =  $this->_productCollectionFactory->create()
            ->addAttributeToFilter('status', '1')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('featured', '1');
        $collection->setVisibility($this->_catalogProductVisibility->getVisibleInCatalogIds());
        $collection = $this->_addProductAttributesAndPrices($collection)
            ->setPageSize(4)
            ->setCurPage(1);

        return $collection;
    }
}
```

In my page, I duplicate one line that is working (the second line is working code):

```
{{block class="MyModule\MySite\Block\Products\Featured" template="WorkingModule_WorkingSite::products/featured_carousel2.phtml" limit="10" category_id="71" block_name="Featured Products"}}
{{block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct" template="WorkingModule_WorkingSite::products/featured_carousel2.phtml" limit="10" category_id="71" block_name="Featured Products"}}
```

Nothing is displayed for the first line and when I debugged, `getTemplate()` seems to be null.
Does anybody see what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to create a product list for featured products in Magento 2. No need to create a custom module. It is simple. Follow these steps.

1. Copy the vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list.phtml file and paste it into the path app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml
2. Rename this above copied file with featured_carousel2.phtml
3. Add the js code into for slider.
4. Then Use the paste the below code in which you want to add.

   ```
    {{block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct" template="Magento_Catalog::product/featured_carousel2.phtml" limit="10" category_id="71" block_name="Featured Products"}}
   ```